# How to access arraylist from another class for which the main purpose of the class is not the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, import, get, tostring

I've read pages and pages of stackoverflow to try to fix my problem and reworked my coding many times to no avail. I wish I could simplify my question, but I'm not entirely sure I know what it going wrong in my code.

I am in the stages of creating a game for a class I'm taking. Thus far, the code involves a parent class for creatures, and child classes of creature types (animal, NPC, etc), which are loaded rooms, another class. I have created a SAXParser to parse an xml file that contains the details of each creature and room, so as to fill out the game with rooms and creatures in each room. My check for the current assignment is to print out the contents of a given room when the user gives the name of the room it would like to see. The rooms are held in the roomArrayList. I have created a main class that holds the responsibility of processing user input.

The rooms ARE filled with the right things. When I set the "EndElement" method in the parser to print the contents of the room that was just created, the output is correct.

However, when I try to print the contents of one of the rooms per the user's request from the main class using the roomArrayList, I get exceptions. I imported the array into the main class with a get method, as you'll see below. I can tell something is wrong because when I print the size of the imported array, it prints zero.

I won't bother to include the creature parent class and the subclasses.

Here is the MyHandler class:

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<Room> roomList = null;
    private Room r;
    private PC pc;
    private String south, north, west, east;


    ArrayList<Room> roomArrayList = new ArrayList<Room>();

    public ArrayList<Room> getArrayList() {
        return roomArrayList;
    }

    public int checkRoomMatch(String match) {
        int a = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < roomArrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (roomArrayList.get(i).RoomName.equals(match)) {
                a = i;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public void startDocument() {
        System.out.println("Document parsing started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String
            qName, Attributes attributes) {

        if (qName.equals("room")) {
            r = new Room(attributes.getValue("name"));
            r.setDescription(attributes.getValue("description"));
            r.setState(attributes.getValue("state"));
            north = attributes.getValue("north");
            west = attributes.getValue("west");
            east = attributes.getValue("east");
            south = attributes.getValue("south");

            r.setNeighbor(south, north, east, west, roomArrayList);

            roomArrayList.add(r);
        }
        else if (qName.equals("animal")) {
            Animal animal = new Animal
                    (attributes.getValue("name"), attributes.getValue("description"),
                            r, qName);
            r.addCreature(animal);
        }
        else if (qName.equals("NPC")) {
            NPC npc = new NPC(attributes.getValue("name"),
                    attributes.getValue("description"), r, qName);
            r.addCreature(npc);
        }
        else if (qName.equals("PC")) {
            pc = new PC(attributes.getValue("name"),
                    attributes.getValue("description"), r, qName);
            r.addCreature(pc);
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri,
                           String localName,
                           String qName) {

        if (qName.equals("room")) {
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
    }

    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("Document parsing ended.");
    }
}
```

Here is my Room class:

```
public class Room {

    Creature[] CreatureArray = new Creature[10];
    String RoomName;
    private int CreatureCount = 0;
    String description;
    String currentState;
    final String Dirty = "dirty";
    final String HalfDirty = "half-dirty";
    final String Clean = "clean";

    // 0 is north, 1 is east, 2 is south, 3 is west
    private Room[] roomArray = new Room[4];

    public Room(String name) {
        RoomName = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.currentState = state;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return RoomName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String roomInfo = "";
        roomInfo += "This room is called" + RoomName + "." + "\n";
        roomInfo += "The following animals are in this room: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < CreatureCount; x++) {
            roomInfo += CreatureArray[x].toString();

            if (x < CreatureCount - 1) {
            }
        }

        roomInfo += "\n" + "The description for room " + RoomName + " is: 
        " + description + ". " + "\n ";
        roomInfo += "The current state of room " + RoomName + " is " +
                currentState + "." + "\n";
        roomInfo += "Room " + RoomName + " is positioned with room " +
                "roomArray[0]" + " to the north, room "
                + "roomArray[1]" + " to the east, room " + "roomArray[2]"
                + " to the south and room "
                + "roomArray[3]" + " to the west." + "\n";

        return roomInfo;
    }

    public void addCreature(Creature a) {
        if (CreatureCount < 10) {
            CreatureArray[CreatureCount] = a;
            CreatureCount++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This room is full.");
        }
    }

    public void setNeighbor(String south, String north, String east,
                            String west, ArrayList<Room> roomArrayList) {

        if (roomArrayList.size() >= 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < roomArrayList.size(); i++) {
                if (roomArrayList.get(i).RoomName.equals(north)) {
                    roomArray[0] = roomArrayList.get(i);
                    roomArrayList.get(i).roomArray[2] = this;
                    continue;
                }

                if (roomArrayList.get(i).RoomName.equals(south)) {
                    roomArray[2] = roomArrayList.get(i);
                    roomArrayList.get(i).roomArray[0] = this;
                    continue;
                }

                if (roomArrayList.get(i).RoomName.equals(east)) {
                    roomArray[1] = roomArrayList.get(i);
                    roomArrayList.get(i).roomArray[3] = this;
                    continue;
                }

                if (roomArrayList.get(i).RoomName.equals(west)) {
                    roomArray[3] = roomArrayList.get(i);
                    roomArrayList.get(i).roomArray[1] = this;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the main method, where user inputs are processed. I've commented out the command to print the size of the imported array. But do recall that when that line is ran, the output it zero. The println command below it is the function that is supposed to work that should print the contents of the selected room.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        File f;
        Scanner fs = null;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a file name:");

        String fileName = kb.nextLine();

        f = new File(fileName);

        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("Enter a file name:");
        }

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        saxParser.parse(fileName, new MyHandler());

        System.out.println("Enter the name of a room for which you would " +
                "like to see the contents.");

        String selectedRoom = kb.nextLine();

        ArrayList<Room> roomArrayList = handler.getArrayList();

        int roomIndex = handler.checkRoomMatch(selectedRoom);
        while (roomIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("No such room existed in the input file.");
            System.out.println("Enter the name of a room for which you " +
                    "would like to see the contents.");
            selectedRoom = kb.nextLine();

            roomIndex = handler.checkRoomMatch(selectedRoom);
        }
        //        System.out.println(roomArrayList.size());
        System.out.println(roomArrayList.get(roomIndex).toString());
    }
}
```

I hope I've created this question correctly. This is my first time making a question because I really feel I've exhausted my resources.

tl;dr -- Why is my filled roomArrayList not being imported into my main method?

Comment: What you did is a good solution - simply add a "getter" method.  SUGGESTION: change the method name from "public ArrayList<Room> getArrayList()" to "`public List<Room> getRooms() {...}`".

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a new instance of MyHandler to Parser where in that instance your array list will be populated and not in you existing handler instance and hence it remains empty.

So instead of passing new hanlder use existing handler like:

```
saxParser.parse(fileName, new MyHandler());
```

Use:

```
saxParser.parse(fileName, handler);//now handler will be having array list populated with rooms and you could use it further.
```

Comment: :O Wow! That fixed it! Thank you SO SO SO much. I am indebted!